# Minimise $f(x,y)=6x^2+3y^2-6xy+15x-9y+1$ subject to constraints

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, optimization, quadratics, maxima-minima

Minimise $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R},(x,y) \mapsto f(x,y)=6x^2+3y^2-6xy+15x-9y+1$ under the condition that

(a) $2x+y\leq 4$

and separately under the condition

(b) $2x+y \geq4$

I'd normally use the method of Lagrange multipliers, but first: I think you'd have to be able to state the conditions in a way that $g(x,y)=0 $ and to me it isn't obvious how. Furthermore, it was given as a hint to just look for the usual minima and maxima of the function and then "check the rest by plugging it in".

So I found an extremum ( the only one ) at $(-1,\frac{1}{2})$ and because the Hessian is positiv definite ( I calculated the eigenvalues ) it's a minimum.

**Now for $(-1,\frac{1}{2})$ (a) holds, but (b) doesn't. I can't see how both could hold for $2x+y \neq 4$ and since there is no minimum for which that is true, how do I minimise the function?** Does there simply not exist a minimum?

Comment: Just out of curiosity : are you sure about the typing of $(a)$ and $(b)$ ? The problem looks so strange (at least to me). Cheers.

Comment: Thanks. But I am probably dumb since I do not see what it could be else than $2x+y=4$.

Comment: I see know it says minimise the function [...] under the following conditions (a) ... (b). In other words, it doesn't explicitly say that they both need to be met simultaneously. Would that make more sense? To check them independently ?

Comment: The story is totally different if they are two distint problems.

Comment: I think you are right then, I'm sorry. Does that mean for (a) it would be the minimum? What would I need to do for b?

Comment: one way is to check KKT conditions. see e.g.: http://mat.gsia.cmu.edu/classes/QUANT/NOTES/chap4/node6.html

Comment: Try using Lagrange multipliers with the condition 2x+y=C and then let C<4 and C>4 respectively

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. $2x+y\leq4$.
   Let $x=-1$ and $y=\frac{1}{2}$.

Hence, we get a value $-\frac{35}{4}$.

We'll prove that it's a mimimal value.

Indeed, we need to prove that
$$6x^2+3y^2-6xy+15x-9y+1+\frac{35}{4}\geq0$$ or
$$2x^2-(2y-5)x+y^2-3y+\frac{13}{4}\geq0,$$
for which it's enough to prove that
$$(2y-5)^2-8\left(y^2-3y+\frac{13}{4}\right)\leq0$$ or
$$(2y-1)^2\geq0,$$
which is obvious.

2. $2x+y\geq4$.

By the same way we can prove that for $(x,y)=(0.65,2.7)$ we'll get a minimal value $0.325$.

Done!